# How to collapse console.trace() by default

Tags: firefox, developer-console

I am working in a Magento 2 project and there are many `console.trace()` messages flooding my developer console and it consumes unnecessary time to scroll past them and find the logs which interest me.

Is there a way to collapse or remove them somehow?